# Within the context of the code below, why is "cout << c" legal while "c = "x"" illegal?

Tags: c++, reference, auto

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of keyword 'auto' and reference. I saw this question and answer online.

> Is the following range for legal? If so, what is the type of c?

```
const string s = "Keep out!";
for (auto &c : s){ /*... */ }
```

And the answer is:

> Depending on the code within for loop body. For example:

```
cout << c;  // legal.
c = 'X';    // illegal.
```

No explanation was provided. Could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: The type of `c` does not depend on the loop body at all. That's not how the C++ type system works in general, with only one exception that I know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the string is *constant*, you may not modify it.  The range-based loop is using the type `auto &` which will effectively become `const char &`.  That means you're referencing characters in the actual string, not copies of them.

Answer (score 3):

Because `s` is a const string so you can't change the value on it. In this case, the type of `c` will be `const char&`.